# Including jQuery on node.js/npm

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm

I'm new to Node, so I apologize if this is a trivial question.

I am trying to include jQuery into a NodeJS project.

From what I've read, it should be as simple as

```
npm install jquery
```

(to install the jquery packages and dependencies to the project folder), then add

```
require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
    }
var $ = require("jquery")(window);
});
```

However, when I do this, Node reports 
`TypeError: require(...).env is not a function`.

I've tried simply `var $ = require("jquery")`, at which it reports `jQuery requires a window with a document`.

I have a feeling that this has to do with cyclical dependencies, but I haven't been able to find which ones need to be removed in such a way that both jquery and jsdom work together.

Comment: The problem appears to be with jsdom, not jquery. I'm not too familiar with that package, but the issue seems to be that the `env` function is not defined.

Comment: Also see [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)

Comment: `.env` is part of the jsdom ["old" API](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/450b915cc68b6581b9b26a312837fa993ef8b4cd/lib/old-api.md). Maybe it's been deprecated?

Comment: you also need to install jsdom `npm install jsdom`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with JQuery in nodejs?

Comment: I'm primarily interested jQuery's ajax suite.